# Create hash map from retrofit response

Tags: android, json, hashmap, response, retrofit

This is my JSON response

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "aaa",
  },
{
    "id": 2,
    "username": "bbb",
  },
{
    "id": 3,
    "username": "ccc",
  }
]
```

I want to create a Hash map(id,username) from the response I get from my server and store it, so that I can use this hash map across all activities.

Answer (score 0):

use this:-

```
HashMap hashMap=new HashMap();
hashMap.put("id",id);
hashMap.put("username",username);
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the JSONObject and create HashMap:

```
 HashMap<String, String> userData = new HashMap<String, String>();
 for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject j = myArray.optJSONObject(i);
   Iterator it = j.keys();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
      String n = it.next();
      userData.put(n, j.getString(n));
   }
}
```